# Qualtrics - formatting answer box for currency,with commas and cents

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Does anyone know how to format Qualtrics text entry box such that it displays a dollar sign, commas, cents automatically. In other words, I want to structure the text entry box so that when a respondent types 100 it becomes $100.00.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks1

Comment: What have you tried?  The general idea of this site is for programmers to help each other.  It isn't a free programming service.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/autoNumeric-1.9.18.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function($) {
      $('.amount').autoNumeric('init', { aSign: '$ ', vMin: '-999999.99' ,  vMax:'999999.99' });  
    });  
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" class="amount" name="amount" id="amount">
</form>
</html>
```

Textbox displays a dollar sign, commas, cents automatically.